# Popup during visual flow

Tags: flow, popup

Is it possible to open a popup during the execution of a flow?

For example, if the user clicks on a specific text or button, the page opens a popup to show some information (like a Visualforce, for example), but does not change the current flow page.

We need this for users to check some information (like a list) before proceeding to the next Flow step.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this isn't possible as it would be a useful feature but I couldn't see how flow would do it without navigating to a new screen.

Comment: @DaveHumm what about a link to open a popup? Like literally opening a popup with a visualforce, passing something in the page parameters. Is it possible to get a link into the flow page without changing the current page?

Comment: Something like that can work as I have flows where we go out to a VisualForce page that allows an attachment to be added to an object created by the flow and then resuming the flow after the actions on the VF page have been completed.  The only thing is it completely switches to the VF page rather than appearing as a popup over the flow then we have it going to a different page rather than the one where the VF was invoked from.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work exactly like a popup but if a variable is set in a Flow after the Next button is pressed then a VisualForce page can be navigated to and then after the actions on the VisualForce page have been completed a page in the flow can be returned to.

In the case where I have done it the page is the next one in the flow rather than the one where it had caused the VisualForce was invoked from but I think a decision in the Flow could be used to navigate back to the calling page if required.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. But if the client doesn't want the user to be moved from one page to another, then this wouldn't work. I'll take a look and see if we can do things this way. Seems the more painless one.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira There's a Dynamic Flow feature coming up, so see if you can wait for it or not...